# Is it safe to plug amplifier's headphone output into the computer?

Tags: microphone

I'd like to record a spoken voice track, but I don't know if the devices will play well together. My main concern is not exploding anything :) I did try and Google this (for hours) but couldn't find any definitive answers.

What I'd like to do is plug an AKG D880 microphone into a Fender Frontman PR241 amplifier, and then plug the amplifier's headphone output into the microphone input of my computer. Is it OK to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A headphone output and a line input should have the same or close impedance.  It shouldn't damage a mic input, but it might be overly loud and noisy.  The line input should work well though.